# Как можно реализовать закрытия сайта по кнопке

Tags: javascript

Пробовал использовать метод window.close(); но он работает не во всех браузерах и в консоли появляется строка: Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Comment: с чего вы взяли, что это вообще можно сделать? и, главное, зачем.

Comment: Ну, с того, что частично это работает, но не везде, а там, где работает - работает через раз. А зачем?Идеи у всех разные) Такова задумка.

Comment: @PavelBogdanov это работает только если вы сами выполнили это в консоле или вы сами открыли это окно посредством js [Window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

Comment: Тут нужно имитировать открытие и потом сразу закрытие, только так, должно везде работать.

Comment: Вам собственно `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.` и говорит, что можно закрывать только те окна, которые были открыты через скрипт. Можно еще попробовать поймать `focus` на вкладке и попробовать закрыть.